# Embedding plots in kivy

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy, bokeh

I found three possible options for including scientific data in kivy and cannot decide which to choose.

- Using [graph from kivy garden](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph):

Pretty simple to implement. Easy to animate. Difficult to create high quality graphs. I am missing (or haven`t found it) features for manipulating line style, marker style and legends. There is a [bug](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/issues/7) which occurs when using different screens, scroll views and carousells.

- Using [Matplotlib kivy backend](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib):

Havent tested it yet. In my opinion the most promising approach.

- Rendering static files: E.g [html created by bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html). Or png by matplotlib.

Are there other solutions ? Has anyone tested the matplotlib backend (possibly with animations) and how mature is it ? Does it make sense to plot real time data (~ 1 Hz sampling rate) using static plots ?

Comment: I think a 1Hz sampling rate should be fine, but haven't tried the matplotlib backend myself.

Comment: When displaying html (bokeh) you need to somehow render the html, which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378036/a-simple-web-page-inside-kivy-app-as-a-widget) digs into.