# A simple web page inside kivy app as a widget

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to have a web view in my kivy application that is running on ubuntu 64bit. I looked on the web, went through kivy's documentation and searched for answers on StackOverflow but I couldn't find anything that can do my job. A simple web page needs to be rendered inside kivy app as widget. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't native support for this.  Try checking out [this](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.cefpython) and [this](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython).

Comment: Yes, this is the only solution I could find but it is so badly maintained. There are no proper docs and I am facing so many issues that I just cannot find a solution to!

Comment: @user2507 Have you looked into tkinter modules?  You can run tkinter from within kivy (I'm using a tkinter file dialog in one of my apps).  I don't think it's encouraged or the best practice but I couldn't find a native-like dialog solution in kivy; you may find a solution like that.

Comment: tkinter itself does not support webview.

Comment: Try wxPython https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.html2.WebView.html

Comment: In kivy-garden I am facing this exact same issue: https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.cefpython/issues/5 ; But I am not able to find those binaries they are talking about. Can you help me with that?

Comment: If you have a separate question, please post it separately.